# Buck converter output voltage dips and makes noise when connecting 1A load

Tags: buck, converter

I've designed a buck-converter board using a ROHM [BD9F500QUZ-E2](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/switching_regulator/bd9f500quz-e.pdf) for 12 V output. Input will be connected to a 4S battery.

On no-load conditions, the IC outputs 12 V, and when the IC is loaded with 500 mA (20 Ω, 30 W load resistor) it delivers the current.

But when 1 A load is connected (10 Ω load resistor) the IC's output voltage dips to 3 V and the inductor starts to make weird noises.

Please help me to find the root cause of this issue.

I'm attaching the schematics and layout.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your inductor saturating by any chance? What input voltage do you measure at 1 A output current?

Comment: Hi Winny, I'm using "ASPI-0630HI-4R7M-T15" inductor, and it's rated for 10A saturated current. currently, I've loaded only 1A. And I/P voltage is 14V. but output current is around 200mA (3V) loading 1A current.

Comment: What’s the peak inductor current at 1 A load? What’s the input voltage at this load?

Comment: Feedback should be taken after the output caps ; taking it before the output caps means it will sense more switching spikes which can trigger the chip's output OVP and cause it to shut down for a few cycles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is a decoupling issue. Are there no vias stitching the top and bottom ground planes together? I can't see any in the images provided.

If not, there is a HUGE route for the ground current from the input capacitors to the ground pins on the regulator.
[image: Huge current loop]

You could try removing some solder mask on the other side of the VIN-trace and rotate the input capacitors 180° around to ground close to the ground pins of the regulator.

I've seen this exact behavior with other regulator designs with bad decoupling. Works somewhat fine (but often with excessive ripple if checked with an oscilloscope) at light load, but it all crashes with increased load.

Comment: thanks for your effort to check, I will put one more I/p decoupling capacitor. with ic ground and will let you know.

Comment: Dear Klas-Kenny, it worked after the changes, Thanks a ton for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Feedback should be taken after the output caps ; taking it before the output caps means it will sense more switching spikes which can trigger the chip's output OVP and cause it to shut down for a few cycles.

Also the input caps are on the wrong side of the input trace, if they have too much inductance to GND, VIN will dip when the top MOSFET turns on, and that will trigger the chip's UVLO and cause it to restart. I had one buck fail due to this, the cause was a little bit of shared trace from the input caps to the chip's VIN and the power MOSFET drain. Fix was to split the trace in two lengthwise with a blade: the MOSFET no longer pulled VIN down, and UVLO did not trigger.

Comment: bobflux Thanks for your explanation. On feed backside, I followed the datasheet and layout recommendation.  Will taking the feedback from output bulk capacitor reduces the frequency switching speed?

Comment: It won't change the switching speed. But I think the problem is input caps on the wrong side of the Vin trace, since I don't see any ground vias.

Comment: True, I've changed and for input caps and it started working fine. appreciate your effort for helping me out.

Comment: Excellent news!

Comment: @bobflux With a wide trace like that, it will be a negligible difference if the feedback connection would be moved to the other side of the caps. I agree, it's best-practice to route the feedback from after the output capacitors, but it won't make any significant difference.